# Trying to filter a dataframe with regex created through the read.csv function in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to filter a dataframe in R that I have created with reading an Excel CSV with:

```
    data <-  read.csv(file="C:/Users/gskyle/Desktop/Keyword Planner.csv",
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             header = TRUE)
```

It looks like:

```
keyword
london venues to hire.
:
how to get a gig in london
0
buy a pub in london)
london blues bars909
jazz vortex!
london events tickets
happenings in london
```

I want to remove the rows that contain punctuation and numbers so using dplyr, I use:

```
require(dplyr)

filtered.data <- filter(data, !grepl('[:digit:]|[:punct:]', keyword))
```

However, my result is:

```
filtered.data

  keyword
1       0
```

Th 4th row only remains and it is a digit. I have tried stating the encoding in the read.csv function as `encoding = "ANSI"`but no luck. Can someone please help?

Comment: I think your regular expression should be '([:digits:]|[:punct:])'--note the parentheses.  (I haven't tested this yet).

Comment: Is `dplyr` really necessary here?

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven, I don't have to but if I use `data[!grepl('[:digit:]|[:punct;]', data$keyword), ]` , I get the same result

Comment: Okay, so what will the desired result look like?  Could you please edit that in?

Comment: Probably `df[!grepl("\\d|[[:punct:]]", df$keyword), , drop=FALSE]` which is basically the same as the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% filter(!grepl("[[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]", keyword))

                     keyword
1 how to get a gig in london
2      london events tickets
3       happenings in london
```

Per @RichardScriven's comment, you can do this in base R as follows:

```
data[!grepl("[[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]", data$keyword),]
```

But if you want to keep all the text while removing numbers and punctuation, you can do this:

```
data %>% mutate(keyword = gsub("[[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]", "", keyword)) %>%
  filter(keyword != "")

                     keyword
1      london venues to hire
2 how to get a gig in london
3        buy a pub in london
4          london blues bars
5                jazz vortex
6      london events tickets
7       happenings in london
```

Note that you need double braces, rather than single, and the class for digits is `[[:digit:]]`, rather than `[[:digits:]]`. Also, you can save some typing by using `\\d` instead of `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo how I had `[:digits:]`. Thanks for you answer. Nailed it